# Free bootstrap template needed for limousine service

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can some please suggest some free bootstrap templates. I want to create a website but do not want to create a design from nothing. The site will be for a limousine service. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at: http://startbootstrap.com/

With regards to having a template that would be suitable for a limousine service, that's really going to be down to you and what you want the website to be styled like.

Personally I would have the top of the page dominated by a carousel showing the fleet of limousines that are available, but that's just me.

I'm sure you'll find a suitable and fitting design from the site mentioned.

Comment: thanks although its not something i asked but u atleast try to answer it thanks for ur help mate